# How to limit user feedback?

Tags: php, mysql, post, button

I'm trying to create a like/dislike system where the user would be able to give feedback for a video. The system works, however the user has no limit as to how many times they can like or dislike.

I thought about making a table to check which user liked which video. I already have two tables, one for the video and another for the user. I wanted to know if that would be a good idea, or if there's a better way of me going about this.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "config.php";

if(isset($_POST["submitted"])){
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE video SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE (v_id = '$vid')");
};
?>
<br>
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted">
    <button type="submit">Like</button>
</form>
```

Below is the mySQL code,

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE video(
v_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
video_name VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
id INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY user_id(id)
REFERENCES users(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE,
n_views INT,
likes INT,
dislikes INT,
image_name VARCHAR(225) NOT NILL
);
```

Comment: I don't see anything in what you posted that attempts to limit someone from voting more than once. At the very least you'll need to know the users id and then check a table you don't yet have to see whether or not that id has voted for the id of the video.

Comment: I haven't created a third table to check for the user id and the video id yet because I wanted to know if it was a bad idea. I was once told that too many tables might create issues on the site.

Comment: Don't know who told you that but it isn't really true (at all). Your additional table just needs to keep the user id and video id so you can easily see if a person has already voted. It's a binary result, yes they have or not they haven't.

Comment: just make another table that holds the REAL likes and dislikes and then run your queries on that table, then add a simple trigger that updates the movie table(s) total count when you do a INSERT on that other table. That way when you do a INSERT user (unique), v_id (unique), type (tiny_int, 0 = dislike, 1 = like), comment (varchar 255), etc, the database will return a duplicate key error when they have already commented on a specific movie v_id

Answer (score 1):

**Easy way** (can be bypassed)

Write a cookie. And check it upon vote.

**Reliable way**

Log every Like/Dislike for user and video. Check for existance upon vote.